# How to set columns correctly at DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have an Dataframe with Columns symbol, YEAR, netIncome and change. The DataFrame has 2 YEARS, which should be both columns with the netIncome.
(Is it easier to change the SQL Statement?)

```
          symbol  YEAR(date)    netIncome change
quarter
Q1       1037.HK        2019      2893750
Q1       1037.HK        2020      2566500
Q2       1037.HK        2019      2268550
Q2       1037.HK        2020      2586250
```

How it should be:

```
          symbol    YEAR1(2019)   YEAR2(2020)  change
quarter
Q1       1037.HK     2893750       2566500
Q2       1037.HK     2268550       2586250
```

Thanks for all helpfull comments

Comment: Look at ```pivot```

Comment: `pd.pivot(df, index=['quarter','symbol'],columns=['YEAR(date)'],)`